# Exclusively access a table and prevent other queries, even read queries

Tags: sql-server, transaction, isolation-level

I'm stuck at setting transaction isolation level. Here's my scenario that happens in the application:

1. Get unprocessed messages (using the `IsProcessing` flag)
2. Set their `IsProcessing` to true (in RAM) and update their `IsProcessing` status
3. Do the business
4. Set their `IsProcessing` to false (in RAM) and update their `IsProcessing` status

This works fine when runs sequentially. But when I run multiple instances of my application (concurrency), I see that some messages are processed twice or thrice. Here's what happens:

1. Instance A gets some unprocessed messages
2. While instance A is setting the `IsProcessing` to true in RAM, instance B gets some messages, and chances are that it fetches one or more of the messages which are already fetched by instance A

And this is what I've done in hope of preventing it:

1. **Begin transaction (serializable)**
2. Get unprocessed messages (using the `IsProcessing` flag)
3. Set their `IsProcessing` to true (in RAM) and update their `IsProcessing` status
4. **Commit transaction**
5. Do the business
6. Set their `IsProcessing` to false (in RAM)
7. **Begin transaction (serializable)**
8. Update their `IsProcessing` status
9. **Commit transaction**

I don't know why, but during steps **1** to **4**, other instances can still perform **read** queries. This is not desired. I want to exclusively prevent anything, even read queries from being executed on messages table during step 1 to 4.

How can I do that? What am I missing in my design? The goal is to make sure that while a message is queued for processing, no other instance would process it again.

Comment: Not sure about all your steps here but it looks like you at least need a query hint in step 2 `with (updlock)` to prevent other threads running this code to fetch the same rows at the same time.

Comment: @MikaelEriksson thanks for the clue. I'm searching now.

Comment: If you use **serializable** other sessions might still read if they use **read uncommitted**, but both **read committed** and **repeatable read** should be blocked.

Comment: Have a look at [Using tables as Queues](http://rusanu.com/2010/03/26/using-tables-as-queues/) by Remus Rusanu.

Comment: @dnoeth, even other serializable transactions can still read. Test it. Two SSMS windows, both `set transaction isolation level serializable; begin transaction; select * from Messages;`. Both with return record set.

Comment: @MikaelEriksson, thanks for you comment. `with (updlock)` doesn't prevent read queries, but `with (tablockx)` does the trick. However, I think using `output` clause as mentioned in the answers would be more efficient, as the whole steps of 1 to 4 would be squeezed into 1 step.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will be able to avoid a lot of your race conditions by performing many of your steps in a single statement. By using a `TOP()` cluse will be able to set the flag on at most one row.  By using the `OUTPUT` cluse you can return this to the application automically.

I define a simple test table and populate it:

```
create table dbo.T(id int, IsProcessing bit default 0);

insert dbo.T(id) values (1),(2),(3),(4);
```

The output clause needs a table variable to receive the changed values:

```
declare @U table (id int);
```

A bit of debug code to make the "before" and "after" states obvious:

```
select 'Before' as B, * from dbo.T;
```

And the statement itself:

```
update top (1) dbo.T
set IsProcessing = 1
OUTPUT INSERTED.id
INTO @U(id)
where IsProcessing = 0;
```

And the results:

```
select 'After' as A, * from dbo.T;
select * from @U;
```

This is the output from the second execution of the above.

```
B       id  IsProcessing
Before  1   1
Before  2   0
Before  3   0
Before  4   0

A       id  IsProcessing
After   1   1
After   2   1
After   3   0
After   4   0

id 
2
```

The row with `id=2` had gone from `IsProcessing=0` to `IsProcessing=1` and that `id` is returned in the table variable.

With this trivial data the rows are processed in the sequence they were created.  In a more complex environment the optimizer may choose any row that matches the where clause.  If you have a requirement to process rows in, say, time sequence further qualification will be required.

I haven't thought it all the way through but I believe his will work at any isolation level with or without explicit transactions.

It is of course possible that there are no rows with `IsProcessing=0` at the time the statement runs. In this case the table variable will have zero rows.

To fully isolate each transaction from the other you could try [`sp_getapplock`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189823.aspx). This will add overhead and reduce concurrency.  You have to be careful to release the app lock as soon as you can in both success and failure scenarios.

Comment: I read about `output` clause, and it seems that there is no need to have a temp table. In other words, this works just fine: `update top (10) Messages set IsProcessing = 1 output inserted.* where (IsProcessing is null or IsProcessing = 0)`

Comment: Go with whatever works in the context of your application.  I put it in the example because I didn't know whether the UPDATE would be stand-alone or, say, part of a larger stored procedure.